# How to display Alert dialog on MacOS using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

How can I display an alert dialog box from a menu item for MacOS apps using `SwiftUI`?
The usual code which works for iOS `@State var isOn = false` and `.alert("title", isPresented: isOn) {..}` doesn't work.

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }.commands {
        CommandMenu("Test menu") {
            Button(action: {
                // I want to show an alert dialog dialog here.
            }) {
                Text("Click Me")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual code works fine. You would never try to stuff an `Alert` inside of a `Button`. You wouldn't do it here.

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {

    @State var isOn = false
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ContentView()
                    .alert("title", isPresented: $isOn) {
                        Button("OK", role: .cancel) { }
                    }
            }
        }.commands {
            CommandMenu("Test menu") {
                Button(action: {
                    isOn = true
                }) {
                    Text("Click Me")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```